# How can I run VS Code's Extension Development Host in a Docker container to test my vscode extension?

Tags: docker, github, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, github-actions

I'm trying to test my vscode extension using GitHub Actions which means that Visual Studio Code needs to be in a Docker container. Has anyone done this? Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done by setting up an ubuntu container withing the workflow and installing vscode. The reason for using a container instead of installing inside the ubuntu-latest itself is so that we can make sure that we start with a clean instance

[Repo Containing Workflow](https://github.com/meroware/vscode-github-actions-example)

[Workflow Installation Run Result](https://github.com/meroware/vscode-github-actions-example/actions/runs/231447801)

**Snippet of workflow containing the setup**

```
ci:
name: Build
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
container:
  image: ubuntu:trusty
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Install vscode
  run: |
    apt-get update
    apt-get clean
    apt-get install -y wget
    wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.microsoft.gpg
    install -o root -g root -m 644 packages.microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
    sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/packages.microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y code
```

**Vscode testing extensions**
From here then we can write any steps necessary to test our extensions as you know
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension